# Redimencionando uma imagem

Tags: c#, imagem

Eu estou tentando redimensionar uma imagem com esse código.

```
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width)
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, image.Height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, image.Height);

        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect);
        }

        return destImage;
    }
```

Entretanto ela está perdendo a qualidade. Essa imagem mostra o código de barras original (com largura 277 pixels) na parte de cima e o redimensionado (com largura de 270) na parte de baixo.

[image: im]

Comment: qual width você tá passando e quais formatos você tá recebendo, como você tá salvando? nos meus testes aqui não granulou

Comment: Eu estou usando o zxing para gerar o código de barras. Qualquer width que eu coloco não é respeitado. A imagem sempre tem 277 de largura.

Comment: Isso tá me aparecendo uma questão na sua impressora e não no códigok